# Working with prepopulated sqlite database in phonegap android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I have an sqlite database test_db.db i have kept in the www folder i am using cordova cli to build android app on my local machine.

when i am trying to open the database it is opening new database instead of accessing the prepopulated.

I tested this using following code.

```
// Open the existing database 

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name : "test_db.db" });

db.transaction(function (tx) {

   alert("database opened");

   var _strQuery = "select * from mst_users;";

   tx.executeSql(_strQuery, [], function (tx, res) {

      alert("Populated Successfully with " + res.rows.length + " Records.");

   }, CommonError);

}, CommonError, DoNothing);
```

And every time i am getting an error that table mst_users does not exist but it is there in the prepopulated db.

I have tried various things for achieving this but yet stucked. I want access the data in the prepopulated database .

Any help is really appreciated..

Comment: Check this link:http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Answer (score 1):

To open prepopulated db in cordova project, you need to do 3 steps:

1. Copy .db file into main www directory

   Install [this](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy) plugin and use copy method(this will copy the .db file
   to the specified directory for your os/device)

   Use [this](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin to open the .db file

Thats it... :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I got the solution for this question.

while opening the database in the folling code

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name : "test_db.db" });

Add a parameter like this

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name : "test_db.db", createFromLocation : 1 });

Then it will take the database which you have kept in the www folder.