# Prepopulate Cordova app files

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

In a Visual Studio Cordova project, other than placing them in `(project)\www` or some subfolder of `(project)\www`, how can I include file assets in my Cordova project such that they are deployed to the device when the app is installed?

And how or on what path do I access them at run-time? If there is Cordova documentation addressing the question of supporting asset deployment, a search term or URL would be much appreciated. I would happily RTFM if I could FTFM.

To illustrate the sort of assets I mean, I'm preparing an app that uses templates to generate forms for the user to fill in, such as a site safety inspection form. It is extremely likely that on first use the user will *not* have the network as many construction sites lack cell coverage. Therefore I need to include
assets that can be used when the network has not yet been available.

If you've ever done over the air upgradeable firmware it's conceptually parallel to the way you implement with base firmware and OTA firmware.

Comment: What do mean by `file assets`?

http://taco.visualstudio.com/ has up to date information on VS2015 + Cordova.  Definitely do a read through and it's well worth the time.

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673365/working-with-prepopulated-sqlite-database-in-phonegap-android/37857340#37857340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli, the www folder contains all web artifacts of your app. So you have to place everything in this folder.

But for sure, you can generate the stuff in the www folder using a task runner like Grunt or Gulp (e.g.: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-grunt.html). I am using it, par example, for minifying my JavaScript and Css files. And also to copy some files from another place into the www folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the project from command line if you have node.js and git installed on your machine.

Navigate to the required folder and then: cordova create appName

Nice guide here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/

Comment: Taco-cli is another great command line tool for cordova by the VS cordova tools team.  You can check it out: https://github.com/Microsoft/TACO or https://www.npmjs.com/package/taco-cli